# Why does toggling an anchor's child element with display cause a double tap, while toggling with opacity does not?

Tags: html, ios, css, touch, mobile-safari

Why does toggling `display` and `opacity` on an anchor's child elements affect touch events differently on iOS devices?

I have a navigation menu in which each item contains an image and a short string of text.

- Each image has a `:hover` state that uses the same shared overlay image.
- If the `:hover` pseudo class sets the overlay image's `display` value, users on iOS devices have to tap the link twice.
- If the `:hover` pseudo class sets the overlay image's `opacity` value, users on iOS devices **do not** have to tap the link twice.
- In both cases, it doesn't matter if the overlay image covers the entire base image or is a smaller inset overlay.
- In both cases, including the `:active` and `:focus` pseudo classes does not change the behavior.

I know that I can just remove the `:hover` rules with JavaScript for touch devices. I'm wondering if anyone knows the **why** there is a difference between `display` and `opacity`.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

a img.overlay {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

a.overlay-display img.overlay {
  display: none;
}

a.overlay-display:hover img.overlay {
  display: block;
}

a.overlay-opacity img.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}
    
a.overlay-opacity:hover img.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Set overlay display:
</p>

<a class="overlay-display overlay-display-first" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"> link text
</a>

<a class="overlay-display overlay-display-last" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0000"> link text
</a>

<a class="overlay-display overlay-display-first" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"> link text
</a>

<a class="overlay-display overlay-display-last" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000"> link text
</a>

<p>
  Set overlay opacity:
</p>

<a class="overlay-opacity overlay-opacity-first" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"> link text
</a>

<a class="overlay-opacity overlay-opacity-last" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/150x150/ff0000"> link text
</a>

<a class="overlay-opacity overlay-opacity-first" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"> link text
</a>

<a class="overlay-opacity overlay-opacity-last" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  <img class="overlay" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000"> link text
</a>
```

Additionally, it doesn't seem to matter if I'm toggling an inline element or a block element. In this snippet, I'm toggling a `span` inside the anchor.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

a.text-display span.overlay {
  display: none;
}

a.text-display:hover span.overlay {
  display: inline;
}

a.text-opacity span.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}

a.text-opacity:hover span.overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Set text display:
</p>

<a class="text-display text-display-last" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"> link text
  <span class="overlay">some other text</span>
</a>

<p>
  Set text opacity:
</p>

<a class="text-opacity text-opacity-last" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"> link text
  <span class="overlay">some other text</span>
</a>
```

According to the iOS Developer Library documentation for [One-Finger Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW4):

> Mouse events are delivered in the same order you'd expect in other web
>   browsers illustrated in Figure 6-4. If the user taps a nonclickable
>   element, no events are generated. If the user taps a clickable
>   element, events arrive in this order: mouseover, mousemove, mousedown,
>   mouseup, and click. The mouseout event occurs only if the user taps on
>   another clickable item. Also, if the contents of the page changes on
>   the mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent.
>   This behavior allows the user to tap in the new content.

[image: Figure 6-4 One-finger gesture emulating a mouse]

The problem is that it's not clear what constitutes a **content change**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting display:none removes the element from the document flow; setting display:block (or display:inline) will put it back into the document flow, which would be a content change akin to creating and adding a new element on the fly.

When you're changing opacity, the element is always in the document flow, just not visible.

Try using display:hidden rather than display:block. If I'm right, display:hidden won't cause you any trouble with double-taps either.  Using "hidden" does not remove the element from the document flow, which is why there's a blank space equivalent to the size of the hidden object when the object is not visible.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the information I was looking for, but couldn't find because I kept thinking it was an event behavior issue. If anyone else is curious, the CSS2 spec defines this behavior in [9.2.4 The 'display' property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop).

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm editing to include the link to the spec; I think that's good info to add.